# htlatex with minted

Tags: htlatex, make4ht

The [minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) package helps to include code in a LATEX document.

It required that `-shell-escape`:

pdflatex -shell-escape document.tex

document.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document} 

\begin{minted}{c} 
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted} 

\end{document}
```

I tried to generate an HTML from that using `htlatex`:

```
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 

?
```

But it complains for that option (`-shell-escape`). How should I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `--shell-escape` (or `-s` shortdd) option provided by `make4ht`:

```
make4ht -s document.tex
```

If you want to use `htlatex`, it is a little bit more involved, as parameters for LaTeX are passed as fifth argument:

```
htlatex document.tex "" "" "" " -shell-escape"
```

`htlatex` passes arguments to three different commands and also to `tex4ht.sty` package. It isn't really much user friendly as you can see.

Comment: 8AFE.pygtex
l.1 --- TeX4ht warning --- \Configure{color}? ---
! Missing { inserted.
\FV@FormattingPrep ...re {color}{\xdef \fv:color }
                                                  \fi \FV@BreakAfterPrep \gl...
l.1 \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
                                         
? I GOT THIS (sorry for the upper case). I got this when I did `make4ht -s document.tex`. Any idea of what might be going on?

Comment: @KcFnMi do you get this for your sample code? I've got no such error. Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: Yes, for that sample code. Using TexLive on macOS. Which one do you use?

Comment: @KcFnMi I use TL on Linux. Could you try to update the distribution?